# Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: javascript, regex, null

Total noob here, I'm currently studying regex in javascript. I have a function that is supposed to pick numbers between 0 and 9 from a string. The function works fine as long as the variable it searches has letters or numbers, however when a null value is entered it gives out the following error:

Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
var lause  = "s0m3 p30pl3";
function tulostanumerot();
var numerot = /[0-9]/g;
   var testi = numerot.test(0-9);

   var setti = lause.match(numerot);
   if (testi === true) {
    console.log(setti.toString());
}
   else {
   console.log("Ei numeroita!");
};
```

Comment: This part does not look correct `var testi = numerot.test(0-9);`

Comment: The function declaration is incorrect; there's no function body.

Comment: can you provide a [mre] showing the error,  the code you provided doesn't produce the type error you described in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about your code:

- The method [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) takes a string argument, which makes this not correct `var testi = numerot.test(0-9);`
- The code is not inside the function `function tulostanumerot();`
- You can omit `testi` at all, and only use `setti`
- Note that [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns either an array or null, so you can use `if (setti) {` instead of checking for true

The code might look like

```
function tulostanumerot() {
    var numerot = /[0-9]/g;
    var setti = lause.match(numerot);

    if (setti) {
        console.log(setti.toString());
    } else {
        console.log("Ei numeroita!");
    }
}
tulostanumerot();
```

```js
function tulostanumerot(lause) {
  var numerot = /[0-9]/g;
  var setti = lause.match(numerot);

  if (setti) {
    console.log(setti.toString());
  } else {
    console.log("Ei numeroita!");
  }
}

[
  "s0m3 p30pl3",
  "",
  "test"
].forEach(v => tulostanumerot(v));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns `null` if no matches are found.

So, you have two options to handle this

1. check if `setti` have a truthy value, you can that like this `if(setti)`.
2. Use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `(?.)` like `setti?.toString()`, .

Answer (score 1):

If you do some `console.log`ging you will see that `lause.match()` returns an array of numbers where the match was found.

**In your case:**

```js
["0", "3", "3", "0", "3"]
```

You are getting an error because `setti` will be null if no matches are found. We can check for it like so.

```js
if (setti) {
   // Setti is not undefined
}
```

Then if you want to combine the elements into a string you can use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead.

```js
if (setti) {
  console.log(setti.join());
} else {
  console.log("Ei numeroita!");
};
```

**Full code:**

```js
var lause = "s0m3 p30pl3";

function tulostanumerot() {
  var numerot = /[0-9]/g;
  var setti = lause.match(numerot);
  
  if (setti) {
    console.log(setti.join(""));
  } else {
    console.log("Ei numeroita!");
  };
}

var lause = "s0m3 p30pl3";
tulostanumerot()

var lause = "no numbers here";
tulostanumerot()
```

Comment: OPs code crashes because `setti` is `null` (for whatever reason), so you'll get similar issues here when trying to use `.join()` on `null`

Comment: @NickParsons Not with optional chaining. But I think I understand what OP wants now.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice the optional chaining edit, that looks good then 

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to check for this. And sould not be hard to find anything online :)

```
if(lause) //Will check if there is any value to the string, which is a non false value. Example: 0, null, undefined false will all fail this statement

OR

if(typeof lause !== "undefined") //Simple but will also pass Arrays and objects

if(typeof lause  === "string" && typeof lause  === "number") //Will only be passed if matching. So if the variable is a array or object it will not be passed
```